# RJ45 crimp connectors for 32 AWG flat cat6 ethernet cable (EU)

Tags: networking, ethernet, network-adapter, cable

Anybody any idea where I can get said RJ45 connectors in the EU, that will ship to Ireland? Seems to be very rare. The dog ate my cable, so I need to crimp it again.

Googling, I could find some reference to it in the US, but nothing in the EU. Amazon UK has one listed, but it is "Currently unavailable".

I have not seen it anywhere else in the EU, so was hoping someone here may have some insights. Otherwise I will have to get it from the US, although I think it will take a few weeks to arrive and I was hoping to get it sooner.

Comment: [BTW, this isn't going to be on topic here, but to throw you a bone…] What specifically are you using as your search? I found some in seconds. Also, check the majors for this kind of thing, not consumer-oriented amazon. RS, Farnell, Canford etc

Comment: Thanks for that Tetsujin, I will look at those. Never knew they existed!